# Design matrix macro interpretation

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

After study the macro section from a SPSS book, I'm still having trouble to understand why/how this code works

```
DEFINE !Combinations (Set = !TOKENS(1) 
                     /Len = !TOKENS(1) ) 
INPUT PROGRAM. 
!LET !Str = " ". 
!LET !LisVar = "". 
!DO !I = 1 !TO !Len 
  !LET !Ind = !CONCAT("#",!LENGTH(!Str)) 
  LOOP !Ind = 0 TO !Set. 
  !LET !Str = !CONCAT(!Str," ") 
  !LET !LisVar = !CONCAT(!LisVar," ",!Ind) 
!DOEND 
VECTOR X(!Len). 
DO REPEAT L = !LisVar /X = X1 TO !CONCAT("X",!Len). 
  COMPUTE X = L.
END REPEAT. 
END CASE. 
!DO !I = 1 !TO !Len 
  END LOOP. 
!DOEND 
END FILE. 
END INPUT PROGRAM. 
EXECUTE. 
!ENDDEFINE.
```

Using the following parameters

```
!Combinations Set = 1 Len = 2.
```

I would have two loops (#1 and #2) going from 0 to 1, which would give me the following set (0,0)(0,1)(1,0)(1,1), but what I don't understand is

i) The first !DOEND shouldn't be at the end, outside the loop?

ii) Why I need this

```
!DO !I = 1 !TO !Len 
  END LOOP.
```

instead of a simple END LOOP?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the point is not for the `loop` to run `!Len` times separately, but to have a hierarchy of loops that's `!Len` levels deep. So the macro first starts the loops, then adds the syntax to run within the loops (at the bottom of the loop hierarchy) and then closes all the loops.
That's why the `loop` command is enclosed in a `!do` macro loop, and so is the `end loop command`.

Comment: Then the code inside the first DO-DOEND is just to start the loops, in this case two loops and just after it the loops are in fact executed?

Comment: The `vector` and the `do repeat` commands are the actual body of the loops - they will run once for every run of the inner loop, which will be repeated once for every run of the outer loop (as in this case there are only two loops)

Comment: Use `set mprint=on` to see the actual syntax created by the macro (in the output), it should make the interpretation much easier.